# Unable to autowire SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, spring-3

I have a little Spring app and I'm attempting to add Hibernate to it. Here is my servlet config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
           ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.vivin"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- View naming conventions -->
    <bean id="viewNameTranslator" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator"/>

    <!-- Controller and action naming conventions -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!-- Resolver for JSP views -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- Turn off working out content type based on URL file extension, should fall back to looking at the Accept headers -->
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/test" />
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.vivin" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have a `DatabaseUserDAO` and a `DatabaseRoleDAO` class both of which implement `UserDAO` and `RoleDAO` respectively. Both implementations have been annotated with `@Repository` as well. I have not implemented any service classes; I just wanted to get up and running to make sure that my configuration is correct.

I cannot figure out what is wrong. When the app starts up, I get the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseUserDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.vivin.myapp.dao.DatabaseUserDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I know that I have defined the session factory in my spring config. Why isn't Spring seeing it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. I was adding the bean declarations for the data source and the session factory to my spring servlet config, instead of `applicationContext.xml`.